# Выравнивание QGridLayout по верхней границе центрального виджета главного окна

Tags: c++, qt

Привожу фрагмент, выполняющий иници-ю GUI. Вопрос следующий, я ожидал первый ряд (по индексу 0) быть выравненным по вершине, т.е. в таком виде, чтобы он граничил с верхом "центрального виджета" главного окна. Htp
Чего я не знаю?
[image: Результат выполнения]

```
void MainWindow::init()
{
    m_gl = new QGridLayout(centralWidget());
    
    m_gl->setGeometry(this->geometry());
    m_gl->setRowStretch(0,0);
    m_gl->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    m_gl->setSpacing(0);
    resize(300,300);

    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 gen(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist6(0,3);

    // Initialize the model.
    for (int index=0;index<16/4;++index)// value for a cell
    {
        m_matrix.append(QVector<bool>({false, false, false, false}));
    }
    int c = 0;
    for (int j=0; j<4; ++j)
    {
        // Refresh the model.
        unsigned row=0, column=0;
        while (isCellTaken(row, column))
        {
            row = dist6(gen), column = dist6(gen);
        }
        m_matrix[row][column] = true;

        // Draw
        char array [3];
        itoa(j, array, 10);
        QPushButton* bp = new QPushButton(array);
        bp->setFixedSize(75,75);

        m_gl->addWidget(bp, 0, c++, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m_gl->addWidget(bp, 0, с++, 1, 1, Qt::AlignTop);
```

Если задать выравнивание ряда в QGridLayout по верхней границе содержащего его виджета, то я получаю требуемую картинку.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]